# Write the output graphql schema variable into a .js file

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

So, I've built this parser for a specific format json files that converts them into a GraphQL schema

```
import jsonToSchema from '../../helpers/json-to-schema.js';
import patientJson from './patient.json';
import valueSetJson from './value-set.json';
import relatedPersonJson from './related-person.json';
import practitionerJson from './practitioner.json';
import encounterJson from './encounter.json';

const patientInput = jsonToSchema(patientJson, true);
const patient = jsonToSchema(patientJson);
const valueSetInput = jsonToSchema(valueSetJson, true);
const valueSet = jsonToSchema(valueSetJson);
const relatedPersonInput = jsonToSchema(relatedPersonJson, true);
const relatedPerson = jsonToSchema(relatedPersonJson);
const practitionerInput = jsonToSchema(practitionerJson, true);
const practitioner = jsonToSchema(practitionerJson);
const encounterInput = jsonToSchema(encounterJson, true);
const encounter = jsonToSchema(encounterJson);

export {
  patient,
  patientInput,
  valueSet,
  valueSetInput,
  relatedPerson,
  relatedPersonInput,
  practitionerInput,
  practitioner,
  encounterInput,
  encounter
};
```

And I have the `schema.js` file like this :

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

import queries from './queries';
import mutations from './mutations';
export default new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({ name: 'Query', fields: queries }),
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({ name: 'Mutation', fields: mutations })
});
```

This process - `jsonToSchema` function - is has lots of recursive functions and can be very resource consuming as the project gets bigger.

So, I was wondering if it's possible to take the resulting schema from such a process to get one big object for the schema as string to save into a `.js` file

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found out my way around this using [fetch-graphql-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-graphql-schema) npm package.

First graphql server has to be built in a away that schema is separated from the resolvers.

Then, I ended up creating a gulp task to save the schema - now it's saved to a `.graphql` file not `.js` - that looks like this:

```
//the dev-server tasks starts the server in development mode
gulp.task('build-schema', ['dev-server'], function getSchema() {
  fetchSchema(config.APP_URL + ':' + config.APP_PORT + '/' + config.GQL_URL_DIR, { readable: true })
    .then(function(schema) {
      fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src/data/schema.graphql'), schema, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Schema saved to: src/data/schema.graphql');
        console.log('Closing server');
        process.exit();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        console.log('Server not loaded, retrying in one second....');
        setTimeout(getSchema, 1000);
      }
    });
});
```

and my `schema.js` will look something like this:

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import schema from './schema.graphql';
import queries from './queries';
import mutations from './mutations';
import resolvers from '../data/resolvers.js';
import { addResolveFunctionsToSchema, makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
let gqlSchema;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  gqlSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schema, resolvers });
} else {
  gqlSchema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({ name: 'Query', fields: queries }),
    mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({ name: 'Mutation', fields: mutations })
  });
  addResolveFunctionsToSchema(gqlSchema, resolvers);
}
export default gqlSchema;
```